# To find all possible grade pairs for a certain value using R

Tags: r, dataframe, math, tidyverse, reshape

I have got a problem statement here, and I am stuck to complete it as a whole.

Here is the statement:

Suppose there are 5 possible grades and associated grade points for each of two
courses. Suppose the grades are A, B, C, D and F and the associated grade points are 4,3,2,1
and 0 respectively. For a randomly selected student, there are nine possible values of his/her
grade point average (GPA) in the two courses and these are (4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0). **For
example, the value 2.5 arises if the student gets grades (A, D), (B, C), (C, B), and (D, A).**

I tried out my level best to write a code for the value of GPA as a function of grades obtained and find all possible grade pairs for a certain value. I could not get the desired output. Can anyone try this out to get the expected output?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a data.frame and a function.
First create a dataset for all combination and GPA and than filter the results.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(grade1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"),
                 grade2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F")) %>% 
  expand.grid(.) %>%
  data.frame(.) %>%
  mutate(points1 = case_when(grade1 == "A" ~ 4,
                             grade1 == "B" ~ 3,
                             grade1 == "C" ~ 2,
                             grade1 == "D" ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0),
         points2 = case_when(grade2 == "A" ~ 4,
                             grade2 == "B" ~ 3,
                             grade2 == "C" ~ 2,
                             grade2 == "D" ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0),
         GPA = (points1 + points2)/2)


df %>% 
  filter(GPA == 2.5)


  grade1 grade2 points1 points2 GPA
1      D      A       1       4 2.5
2      C      B       2       3 2.5
3      B      C       3       2 2.5
4      A      D       4       1 2.5
```

Or you put the whole code in a function:

```
find_combinations <- function(x) {
  df <- data.frame(grade1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"),
                   grade2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F")) %>% 
    expand.grid(.) %>%
    data.frame(.) %>%
    mutate(points1 = case_when(grade1 == "A" ~ 4,
                               grade1 == "B" ~ 3,
                               grade1 == "C" ~ 2,
                               grade1 == "D" ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0),
           points2 = case_when(grade2 == "A" ~ 4,
                               grade2 == "B" ~ 3,
                               grade2 == "C" ~ 2,
                               grade2 == "D" ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0),
           GPA = (points1 + points2)/2)
  
  
  res <- df %>% 
    filter(GPA == x)
  
  return(res = res)
}

find_combinations(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a convenient function that solves this problem in the `dplyr` package. See details at this link including a series of basic, worked examples:

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html